# How to highlight a duplicate word?

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList of Strings, which is displayed in a text area, and I am trying to move the highlighter along one word each time this method is called, but it keeps highlighting the previous word, because it's a duplicate word, instead of the next one. Here's my code:

```
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
                words.add("Word1"); //Keeps highlighting this one twice 
                words.add("Word2");
                words.add("Word1"); //Instead of highlighting this one
                words.add("Word3");

                for(String other : words)
                {
                    textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + "\n" + other);
                }

                int wordNum = 0;

                String word = words.get(wordNum++);

                Highlighter highlighter = textArea.getHighlighter();
                HighlightPainter painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.blue);
                int p0 = textArea.getText().indexOf(word);
                int p1 = p0 + word.length();

                try
                {
                    highlighter.removeAllHighlights();
                    highlighter.addHighlight(p0, p1, painter);
                } catch (BadLocationException ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to highlight each and every word of JTextArea, try this method,

```
Highlighter highlighter = jtextArea.getHighlighter();
    DefaultHighlightPainter painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.blue);
int front=0;

public void highligtNextWord(JTextArea ta)throws Exception{
    String str=ta.getText().trim()+" ";
    int end=str.indexOf(" ",front);
    highlighter.removeAllHighlights();
    highlighter.addHighlight(front, end, painter);
    if(end>=str.length()-1)
        front=0;
    else
        front=end+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are highlighting from **p0** to **p1** which means, from the first index of first occurrence of **word**, you are highlighting the first word, not the second one. To avoid that, use `lastIndexOf()` instead indexOf().

```
int p0 = textArea.getText().lastIndexOf(word);
int p1 = p0 + word.length();
```

Now you will get the last occurrence of the duplicated word, instead of the first one.